# Canvas fillPattern has offset on Chrome, but no on Firefox

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I used Path2D to draw a negative axis path, offset it with translate, and then created a gradient with createPattern. I found that the fill has an offset, and there is an offset on the Chrome browser, which is normal on the Firefox browser.**Why are they different???**

---

**Open this demo on Chrome and Firefox**  https://codepen.io/xiechengjian/pen/vVbNXv 。

my Chrome version:70.0.3538.67
my Firefox version:63.0

```
let p = new Path2D();
ctx.translate(100,100)
p.moveTo(-100,-100)
p.lineTo(100,-100);
p.lineTo(100,100);
p.lineTo(-100,100);
p.closePath()
var offCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
offCanvas.width = 200;
offCanvas.height = 200;
var offCtx=offCanvas.getContext("2d")

offCtx.fillStyle = "red"
offCtx.fillRect(0,0,200,200);
let gradient = ctx.createPattern(offCanvas, "no-repeat");
ctx.fillStyle = gradient
ctx.fill(p)
ctx.stroke(p)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[This a Firefox bug.](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1263776)**

---

First I'd like to clear up what I fear is a misconception here. The Path2D object you created is not connected to your 2D context anyhow before you use it with `ctx.fill(p); ctx.stroke(p);`.
It is only inside these methods that the coordinates of its sub-paths will get transformed to the context's current matrix.
So the `ctx.translate(100,100);` has no effect on the Path2D object, it will have on both context's methods though.

Also, your Path2D is actually just `p.rect(-100, -100, 200, 200)`.
So if we replace all this Path2D code to a simple `ctx.rect()` call, we can see that the discrepancy you noticed is not related to the Path2D API:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.fillStyle = generatePattern();
ctx.translate(100, 100);
ctx.rect(-100, -100, 200, 200);
ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();

function generatePattern() {
  var offCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  offCanvas.width = 200;
  offCanvas.height = 200;
  var offCtx = offCanvas.getContext("2d");
  offCtx.fillStyle = "red";
  offCtx.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
  return ctx.createPattern(offCanvas, "no-repeat");
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="250"></canvas>
```

So what happens, is that the `fillStyle` (and `strokeStyle`) property is like an infinitely big layer, itself relative to the context's transform matrix. When you set it to either a CanvasPattern, or a CanvasGradient, this matters since the position of your bitmap will get ruled by this transformation matrix.

Here is a simple example showing how this can be used, to create a moving gradient, while the sub-path remains the same.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
// we define the gradient only once
ctx.fillStyle = generateGradient();
// we define the sub-path only once
ctx.lineTo(20, 20);
ctx.lineTo(190, 50);
ctx.lineTo(130, 190);
ctx.closePath();

draw({clientX:50, clientY:50});
canvas.onmousemove = draw;

function draw(evt) {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  var x = evt.clientX - rect.left - 50;
  var y = evt.clientY - rect.top - 50;
  // clear
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  // here, all that moves is the fillStyle layer
  ctx.translate(x, y);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
}


function generateGradient() {
  var grad = ctx.createRadialGradient(
    50,
    50,
    0,
    50,
    50,
    25
  ); // a circle whose center is at 50,50, and rad is 25
  grad.addColorStop(0, 'red');
  grad.addColorStop(1, 'green');
  return grad;
}
```

```html
move your mouse over the triangle
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="250"></canvas>
```

In your case, the pattern you created will get moved by 100px on both x and y axis, hence the top-left corner of your *offCanvas* will be rendered at pixel 100,100 and since your Path only renders until pixel 200,200, it will should get cropped.

***But why does Firefox renders it like there is no offset?***
It is entirely a bug of how Firefox renders non-repeating CanvasPatterns.
Using a bitmap image will make it obvious:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {

  ctx.fillStyle = ctx.createPattern(img, "no-repeat");
  ctx.translate(100, 100);
  ctx.rect(-100, -100, 200, 200);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();

};
img.src = 'https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/222/Canvas_createpattern.png';
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="250"></canvas>
```

Results in my Firefox 64:
[image: The image gets stretched in all directions]

So when you used a solid red color as pattern, this bug would actually produce a fully red bitmap, while the correct behavior [according to specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#dom-canvaspattern-settransform) is to render transparent black pixels where the pattern algorithm created no results.

---

For a fix, we'll have to wait for FF to provide it.
But note that in your case, using `fillRect` will workaround the bug.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {

  ctx.fillStyle = ctx.createPattern(img, "no-repeat");
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
  ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, 200, 200);

};
img.src = 'https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/222/Canvas_createpattern.png';
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="250"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you for your patience.But in practice the path2D I need to fill contains the negative axis path both x and y axis. so I have to `translate()` to draw all the paths.I can fill it up with `createRadialGradient()` or `createLinearGradient()`,but not with `createPattern()`.In this case ，How can I fill it up with `createPattern()`.Thank you again

Comment: As I explained, this is a browser bug, and can not be fixed. There is certainly a workaround, but that would be completely dependant on your exact use case. I invite you to write a new question where you would expose the exact case (e.g why it needs to be a non-repeating pattern) in search for a workaround. But for now, I think I gave the answer to "why it differs between Chrome and FF".

Comment: Well，Thank you for solving this problem

Comment: Let me know when you'll write up your new question, I'd be glad to search for a specific workaround if I've got time.

Comment: Maybe I've found a solution, [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20253210/canvas-pattern-offset)

Comment: That will unfortunately not fix FF's bug. Even when the transform is the one of the CanvasPattern rather than the one of the context, they use GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE, so you'll have the same discrepancy.